# soup.findAll scraping the whole webpage

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've been testing BeautifulSoup in python and have been trying to use the find all function to get everything tagged 'a' but when I print soup it spits out the entire webpage, I haven't seen anyone else with this problem and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, code is below. Thanks!

```
# Import libraries
import requests
import urllib.request
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Set the URL you want to webscrape from
url = 'http://sprob.org/'

# Connect to the URL
response = requests.get(url)

# Parse HTML and save to BeautifulSoup object
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

soup.findAll('a')

print(soup)
```

Comment: You are printing soup try printing `soup.findAll('a')`

Comment: soup.findAll('a') will not change the variable soup. You need to set the result of soup.findAll('a') to something, like A = soup.findAll('a') and then print(A)

Answer (score 0):

Lets take a closer look at the last 3 lines:

```py
# Parse HTML and save to BeautifulSoup object
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

soup.findAll('a')

print(soup)
```

You're defining a variable `soup` with a `BeautifulSoup` obj. Then you're calling `soup.findAll('a')` but you're still printing the
`soup` variable, which is the `BeautifulSoup` obj.

---

Instead, we'll need to capture the result of `soup.findAll('a')` and `print()` that. Something like this:

```py
# Import libraries
import requests
import urllib.request
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Set the URL you want to webscrape from
url = 'http://sprob.org/'

# Connect to the URL
response = requests.get(url)

# Parse HTML and save to BeautifulSoup object
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

# Parse all <a>
links = soup.findAll('a')

# Print links
print(links)
```

The above code will output:

```
[<a href="index.html">
<div class="headerL">
<li>Home</li>
</div>
</a>, <a href="about.html">
<div class="headerL2">
<li>About</li>
</div>
</a>, <a href="index.html"><img alt="picture of website logo" class="logo" height="63" src="images/logo.png" width="220"/></a>, <a href="projects.html">
<div class="headerR">
<li>Projects</li>
</div>
</a>, <a href="social.html">
<div class="headerR2">
<li>Social</li>
</div>
</a>]
```